# Is Minio supports MIME type check?

Tags: minio

Is Minio supports MIME type check? For example, when uploading file user can specify what MIME type should be for this file. Than Minio analyzes this file and if it is a correct (e.g it's valid image) save, if not response with an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minio supports AWS S3 API which doesn't implement any MIME type based checking. But you can definitely set Content-Type of the object while uploading and it will be preserved by Minio.